# domain and range and determine whether * defines a binary operation on G?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Define the function $∗ : G × G → G$ by $∗(g_1, g_2) = g_1g_2$ where $G =
\{0, 1\}$. Explicitly write out the domain and range of $∗$ and then determine
whether $∗$ defines a binary operation on $G$. Note: Interpret $g_1g_2$ as ordinary
multiplication.

So, in this case are we defining $∗$ as ordinary multiplication? In that case, would we just have to verify that the set is closed under multiplication, nonempty, and contains the identity? All of these hold true, which makes me believe that $∗$ defines a binary operation, but I don't know if that is the correct way to go about this...

Also, for the domain and range, how would we find that? My initial thought was just that the domain=$0$ range=$1$???? But that does not seem correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be a binary operation,  it just has to take in inputs of all possible ordered pairs of elements of $G$ and output an element of $G$.   So really all you need to do is check closure.

Your domain is the set of ordered pairs, explicitly it'd be $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$
Your range is all the possible values, which in this case is the same as the codomain, $G$, or $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: So because it is closed (any combination of 0's and 1's will only give you 0's and 1's. therefore it must be closed) it does define a binary operation?

Comment: Correct, a binary operation is just a function that takes in all possible ordered pairs of elements of a set and outputs an element of that set.

Comment: So for example, if G={2,3} it would not be closed and therefore not a binary operation?

Comment: @Kaitlyn That is correct

Comment: @Kaitlyn No problem. To really thank me, click the check mark to accept the answer :)